# Grid размер column и выравнивание элементов

Tags: css, css-grid

Есть блок с `display: grid` внутри которого 4 `div`. Грид делится на 3 колонки и два ряда. Нужно сделать, чтобы ширина первой колонки была равна ширине содержимого `<div class="b">`, `<div class="c">` начинался сразу после b, а `<div class="d">` был прижат к правому краю.

Пробовал делать `justify-items: start` но колонки все-равно растягиваются на всю ширину. Более похожего поведения я добился с `justify-content: flex-start;`, но тогда не могу `.d` прижать к правому краю

Для лучшего понимания, прикреплю картинку с желательным результатом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a a d" "b c d";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0 22px;
  height: 60px;
}

.wrap div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  background: yellow;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  background: red;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  background: green;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="b">text b text b</div>
  <div class="a">text a text a</div>
  <div class="d">text d</div>
  <div class="c">text c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А что если использовать пустой столбец с автоматической шириной? как здесь - https://jsfiddle.net/frozencoast/2y1vs9Lg/1/

Comment: @frozencoast поменял на `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto auto;` и получилось то, что надо. спасибо!